# Changes in the way Drupal 7 handles JavaScript and jQuery

Tags: 7, javascript

I'm currently developing a JavaScript script that runs on an administration page. I read up on the changes made in Drupal 7, namely the move from `document.ready()` to its own jQuery function. However, the following script doesn't work.

```js
(function ($) {
  console.log('hello');
  $('#edit-apiusername').append('test');
})(jQuery);
```

`console.log()` is firing and I can see the output, but the simple append doesn't work. The field ID is correct.
I am not sure what I'm missing here, but I suspect it has to do with the way I'm referencing the object. Looking at Views 3 JavaScript code, I can see it's done in a similar way.

Comment: If you console.log($('#edit-apiusername')); does it output the object, ie is the element being found on the page by jQuery?

Comment: Even with Drupal 6 you were supposed to use the Drupal behaviors, instead of `document.ready`. What you are reporting is not specific to Drupal 7.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the changes.

JavaScript code should be wrapped in `(function ($) { ... })(jQuery);` to allow usage of `$` as shortcut to `jQuery`. This is to allow [jQuery to play nicely with other libraries](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries). In this function, you still have to wait for the DOM to be loaded if you want to alter it. That's what wrapping your code in `jQuery.ready(function(){ ... })` does.

But instead of using `jQuery.ready(function(){ ... })`, you should [use behaviors](http://drupal.org/node/756722) to let Drupal's JavaScript knows that your code wants to process anything added ([or removed](http://drupal.org/update/modules/6/7#drupal_behaviors)) from the DOM.

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.exampleModule = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
      $(context).find('#edit-apiusername').append('test');
    }
  }
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

You might  also consider aliasing the whole jQuery object to another variable of your choice, as in:

```
$j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

You would put this outside of the ready statement to leave it accessible outside of the encapsulation.