# Best way for including javascript/jQuery OnLoad in EVERY page on my site

Tags: 7, theming, javascript

Currently, in my theme.info file I am including 2 scripts:

```
scripts[] = js/backstretch.js
scripts[] = js/scripts.js
```

Backstretch is a jQuery plugin that allows for an expanding background image to cover your entire page.

I am currently using this code to autoload the JS:

```
(function ($) {

    var bgs=["bg1.jpg", "bg2.jpg"];
    var bgr=Math.floor(bgs.length * Math.random());
    $.backstretch(bgs[bgr], { speed: 1000 });

})(jQuery);
```

Two issues:

1. Sometimes it doesn't load the backstretch.js properly which may have something to do with my current OnLoad function in scripts.js. It loads the image but not maximum width/height of the browser initially.
2. For some reason, it doesn't work past 1 level in the site (although the JS seems to load when I check the site (could it be that the location of images is not relative of the JS file?) e.g.,:

> Works: site.com, site.com/page
>
> Doesn't Work: site.com/dir/page, site.com/dir/dir/page

I was wondering in my scripts file what would be the best OnPageLoad (or Preload?) function would be best to use?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Now that I think about it, this question is strikingly similar to http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/515/changes-in-the-way-drupal-7-handles-js-and-jquery.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please read [Managing JavaScript in Drupal](http://drupal.org/node/756722#behaviors), specifically the section on Behaviors. You'll need to do something like this:

```
(function ($) {

  Drupal.behaviors.exampleModule = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
      var bgs=["bg1.jpg", "bg2.jpg"];
      var bgr=Math.floor(bgs.length * Math.random());
      $.backstretch(bgs[bgr], { speed: 1000 });
    }
  };

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Can you expand on the "exampleModule" thing? I just want it to run when the best way when the page loads. Would if be "Drupal.behaviours.OnLoad" ? Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: That' s just a variable name for your code. You can use anything, but must use a module prefix. Behaviours are all executed on load.

Comment: Ok I will try it out when I get home, thankyou

Comment: Matt, what did you use instead of "exampleModule"

Comment: @Berdir "Behaviours are all executed on load." - not sure what you mean here, but my understanding is that behaviours are executed when the DOM is ready, i.e. the pure JQuery equivalent is running code inside the `ready` function, as the `ready` function is executed once the DOM is ready.

Comment: Now, this may not be suitable for some folks if they need to do stuff at another point, e.g. not just when the DOM is ready BUT also once the images have all loaded, i.e. the `load` function in JQuery. The convention in Drupal seems to frown upon using JQuery functions directly and rather encourage using the behaviours but using these is fine if you want to run your code when DOM is ready but not fine if you want it to run at another time, I've search for the convention in Drupal for running JQuery code at a point other than `ready` but have been unsuccessful so far :(

Comment: @therobyouknow The main reason to use on ready and similar jquery events directly is that behaviors are integrated with the ajax API, if a part of a page is replaced based on an ajax event, behaviors will automatically be re-executed for that part.